# rails tutorial could not locate gem file when bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I'm new to Ruby on rails and doing the tutorial on railstutorial.org, I'm stuck on the the first chapter about bundler install.I updated my gem file to what version I want them on but when I go to hello_app directory and type bundle install in in my shell I get a "couldn't find gem file". I type LS or ls in the hello_app directory and gemfile.rb shows up. what am i doing wrong? Ive done a search on this topic for 2 hours I have not found a solution. I have rails 4.2.1 installed but i also installed 4.2.0 because the book calls for this version, don't know if thats the cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed rails correctly before creating a new rails app, I'm not sure you'll even need to update your gems with the `bundle install`

Comment: well the tutorial calls for updating your gems for some reason and doing a bundle install. [link](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#code-rails_command) 1.3.1 bundler.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong. I had saved the Gemfile in a .rb extension thinking it was suppose to be a ruby file. thats why it couldn't find the Gemfile. how I found out was just restarting the rails project from the beginning and do it step by step. I found the original Gemfile didn't have the .rb file extension, so when I tried bundle install it worked. thank for the reply @Mba Uchenna.